# A problem with Hilbert's "Foundations of Geometry" I.2 axiom.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, axioms, axiomatic-geometry

In the Hilbert's Foundation there is a $I.2$ axiom:

Any two distinct points of a straight line completely determine that line; that is, if $AB = a$
and $AC = a$, where $B \not= C$, then is also $BC = a$.

But Hilbert don't defines a relation "distinct".
(He defines only theese: "are situated", "between", "parallel", "congruent", "continuous").

So, it looks like that in this formulation, this cannot be an axiom.

Comment: Find a different  text.  That one has a bunch of horrible translation errors. (See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778914/a-confusion-about-the-second-connection-axiom-of-euclidean-geometry and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961169/redunduncy-of-paschs-axiom-of-hilberts-foundations-of-geometry.)

Comment: I have read an original text. So it also contains this relation without defenition

Comment: "Equality" is usually taken as primitive when you're defining an axiomatic theory. In the same way for instance the theory of groups has axioms like "$g \cdot e = g$" without saying what $=$ means. Semantically, it really just means that the objects in question are the same object. If you're proving something, you can assume $=$ is an equivalence relation with the [substitution property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Basic_properties).

Comment: But the theory of groups use sets, so it means that it’s a part of the set theory and it (theory of groups) must use ZFC, where we define “equality”